# SQL Server not applying criteria for first character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
 select * from 
 (select N'Christina  Taylor' name) a
 where name like '[a-z]%'
```

I am expecting the resultset to be empty because the first character is not an alphabet character. But in fact the query above returns a row.

Why is that?

I am using SQL server 2016.

Comment: Does that answer the question of why the row comes up in my query?

Comment: That seems to work, and I am not very clear as to why but now I get results that include names like: ✨Matthew

Comment: The row comes up because the 4 bytes of are considered as NULL (ignored) for a collation without supplementary characters..[a-z]% is applied to the next character which is C-ristina.. try and change the match pattern to [d-z]%…

Comment: @lptr A binary collation also works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2948a6c14b3c0d7a55de2f7fd563ab7f